# Convert html to text in android

Tags: android, html

I want to convert html text to text and put in TextView
But after converting I receive additional paragraphs
Please look at image
[image]

Why indentation and paragraphs appear before a list item?

```
String data = "<ul>\r\n\t<li>\r\n\t\t<p align=\"justify\" class=\"western\" lang=\"ru\" style=\"margin-bottom: 0in\"><font size=\"3\" style=\"font-size: 12pt\"><span lang=\"en-US\">Consumers may return an item for any reason within thirty (30) days of delivery of such items.<\/span><\/font><\/p>\r\n\t<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>\r\n<ul>\r\n\t<li>\r\n\t\t<p align=\"justify\" class=\"western\" lang=\"ru\" style=\"margin-bottom: 0in\"><font size=\"3\" style=\"font-size: 12pt\"><span lang=\"en-US\">The item must be returned to the applicable merchant and must have a verified tracking number.<\/span><\/font><\/p>\r\n\t<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>\r\n<ul>";
```

Function to convert which I use

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(data, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Comment: it is my string html

Comment: I added part of html code, because it is too long

Comment: edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Html.fromHtml(html)
```

where html is the html string

The html is badly formatted, paste it on this online html editor [HTML EDITOR](https://html-online.com/editor/) and see. That might be why the inbuilt converter is not working as expected. Additional info on how .fromHtml works [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    yourTextView.text =
                        Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlData, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
                } else {
                    yourTextView.text = Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlData)
                }
```

[These](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) are the HTML tags that are supported with TextView.